# Unresolved external Vcl::Themes::TCustomStyleServices::DrawTextW

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-10.3-rio, c++builder-10.3-rio

I'm trying to create a VCL application that uses `StyleServices` to do some extra drawing on a custom component. I can use `StyleServices()->DrawElement()` and the application compiles without any issue, but if I use `StyleServices()->DrawText()`, I get a linker error:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Vcl::Themes::TCustomStyleServices::DrawTextW(HDC__ *, Vcl::Themes::TThemedElementDetails&, System::UnicodeString, System::Types::TRect&, System::Set, Vcl::Themes::TStyleTextOptions&, int)' referenced from ...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `Vcl.Themes.hpp` have a [`#pragma alias`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_alias) statement that maps `TCustomStyleServices::DrawTextW` to `TCustomStyleServices::DrawText`? If not, then file a [bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com), and then try adding a suitable `#pragma` to your own code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau A search in `Vcl.Themes.hpp` shows no instance of [#pragma alias](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_alias). I will create a QC ticket for it. Adding `#pragma alias "@Vcl@Themes@TCustomStyleServices@DrawTextW"="@Vcl@Themes@TCustomStyleServices@DrawText"` did not fix the problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've created [RSP-28073](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-28073). Please vote for it.

Comment: Those are not the correct signatures to use for `TCustomStyeServices::DrawText/W()` in a `#pragma alias` statement. You have to use the *full* decorated names, which also includes things like calling convention flags and parameters. Sorry, I don't have the correct symbol name to give you right now. Use TDUMP to get the actual symbol name for `TCustomStyeServices::DrawText()` from the RTL libs, put that full symbol on the right-hand side, then rename `DrawText` to `DrawTextW` and put that full symbol on the left-hand side.